# Tkinter Removing a frame placed onto a canvas works on one canvas but not another

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, frame, destroy

So I am building a card game program to allow 2 players to play against each other (MTG) but I am completely confused over this problem.

So I have 2 canvas's 1 for each players 'battle field' code to generate is the same (with just name changes) and the code to add the 'cards' to each battle field is pretty much the same (few menu's removed for the opponents cards)

When i use frame.destory() on the players card, it works fine and the frame is removed, however when I use it on the opponent card frame the program stalls and goes into not responding.

I'm using python 2.7 and the program stalls in the opponent_card_removed_field routine on card_frame.destroy()

any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code;

Opponent Frame creation code;

```
    def create_opponent_frame(self):
    self.opponent_frame = tk.Frame(self.field, bg='grey11', highlightthickness=0)

    self.opponent_battlefield = tk.Frame(self.opponent_frame, bg='grey11', highlightthickness=0)
    self.opponent_battlefield_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.opponent_battlefield)
    self.opponent_battlefield_canvas.pack(side='top', padx=(2, 2), pady=(2, 2))
    self.opponent_battlefield.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand='True', padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 5))

    self.opponent_frame.pack(side='top', fill="both", expand="True")
```

Player Frame Creation;

```
    def create_player_frame(self):
    self.player_frame = tk.Frame(self.field, bg='grey11', highlightthickness=0)
    self.player_battlefield = tk.Frame(self.player_frame, bg='grey11', highlightthickness=0)
    self.player_battlefield_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.player_battlefield)
    self.player_battlefield_canvas.pack(side='top', padx=(2, 2), pady=(2, 2))
    self.player_battlefield.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand='True', padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 5))

    self.player_frame.pack(side='top', fill="both", expand="True")
```

Player card creation (image is an image file read from a database);

```
    def create_player_battlefield_card(self, card, status, facing):       
        details['card'] = card
        details["card frame"] = tk.Frame(self.player_battlefield_canvas, bg='midnight blue', highlightthickness=0)
        details["card canvas"] = tk.Canvas(details["card frame"], width=75, height=105,
                                           bg='midnight blue', highlightthickness=0)
        details["original"] = image
        details["img"] = details["original"].resize((75, 105))
        details["img"] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(details["img"])            
        details['list index'] = a
        details['count'] = self.player_field
      
        details["object"] = details["card canvas"].create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=details["img"])         

        self.player_battlefield_image_objects.append(details)

        details["card canvas"].pack(side='top')

        self.player_battlefield_canvas.create_window((55, 75), window=details["card frame"], tags=details['count'])
```

Opponent card creation (again image is the image file from a db);

```
    def create_opponent_battlefield_card(self, card, status, facing):
        details['card'] = card
        details["card frame"] = tk.Frame(self.opponent_battlefield_canvas, bg='midnight blue', highlightthickness=0)
        details["card canvas"] = tk.Canvas(details["card frame"], width=75, height=105,
                                           bg='midnight blue', highlightthickness=0)
        details["original"] = image
        details['img'] = image.rotate(180)
        details["img"] = details["img"].resize((75, 105))
        details["img"] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(details["img"])
        details['list index'] = a
        details['count'] = self.opponent_field   

        details["object"] = details["card canvas"].create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=details["img"])

        self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects.append(details)

        details["card canvas"].pack(side='top')

        y = self.opponent_battlefield_canvas.winfo_height() - details["card frame"].winfo_height()
        y -= 75
        self.opponent_battlefield_canvas.create_window((55, y),
                                                       window=details["card frame"], tags=details['count'])
```

Code to remove player card;

```
    def field_to_hand(self, list_index):

    card = self.player_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['card']
    card_frame = self.player_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['card frame']
    status = self.player_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['status']

    if status == 'original':
        self.create_player_hand_card(card)

    card_frame.destroy()

    self.player_battlefield_image_objects.pop(list_index)

    for detail in self.player_battlefield_image_objects:
        if detail['list index'] > list_index:
            self.player_battlefield_image_objects[detail['list index'] - 1]['list index'] -= 1
```

Code to remove opponent card;

```
    def opponent_card_removed_field(self, list_index):
    card = self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['card']
    card_frame = self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['card frame']
    status = self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects[list_index]['status']

    card_frame.destroy()

    print self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects

    self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects.pop(list_index)

    for detail in self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects:
        if detail['list index'] > list_index:
            self.opponent_battlefield_image_objects[detail['list index'] - 1]['list index'] -= 1
```

Edited to reduce code

Comment: for further information I forgot to add.
The 'send message' routine will be used to send the data via socket to the server and then sent to your opponent.for now I have it set to loop back in so its as if the opponent is mirroring every move you make.

If the full program code will help I can add it, but its almost 1600 lines of code

Comment: You've posted far too much code. Please try to condense it down into a [mcve].

Comment: my apologies - I have reduced the code by removing stuff to do with context menus and other parts that should have no impact on the problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems to be some weird quirk in 2.7. I have just ported my code over to python 3.7 and all is good. It runs with none of the problems I was seeing above